# Cylindrical coordinates: why require $0≤\varphi≤\pi$?

Tags: coordinate-systems

In cylindrical coordinates:

Why is there a requirement that $0≤\varphi≤\pi$?

Comment: You'll need to explain in more detail how the particular coordinate system you're asking about works. There is no solid convention about which Greek letters mean what in systems with rotational coordinates, so _a priori_ $\varphi$ could mean anything until you have defined how you use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking what I think you are: If the north pole has $\phi=0$, then the south pole would have $\phi=\pi$ because you just have to walk $\pi$ radians down a line of longitude to get there.

Comment: That's the best sense I can make of the question too -- but it doesn't _quite_ fit because such a coordinate is used only in _spherical_ coordinates, and not for cylindrical ones.

Comment: Yeah that clears it. I was reading that this $\varphi$ was in cylindrical coordinates, but this is only in spherical, which does make sense.